# Pandas data sampling into different ratios using a logic

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, training-data, sampling

I have a data frame like below and i want to sample the data where each customer data  should be split into three buckets into train(70%) , validation(15%) and test(15%) using the order_id.Each customer should be present in all three buckets.The order_id count and items may differ  per customer

Dataframe:

```
Customer  Orderid   item_name
   A        1        orange
   A        1        apple
   A        1        banana
   A        2        apple
   A        2        carrot
   A        3        orange
   A        4        grape
   A        4        watermelon
   A        4        banana
   B        1        pineapple
   B        2        banana
   B        3        papaya
   B        3        Lime
```

All three data sets(train , validation and test) after sampling should contain equal number of customers and items from validation and test  should be subset of train .

Expected result:

```
  train: should contain all customers and all item_names (70% of complete data)
train:
     customer  item
         A     orange
         A     apple
         A     banana
         A     carrot
         A     grape
         A     watermelon
         B     pinepple 
         B     banana
         B     papaya
         B     Lime
  validation : should contain all customers and item_names can be subset of train(15% of complete data)
        customer  item
         A     orange
         A     apple
         A     banana
         B     pinepple 
         B     banana
         B     papaya
         B     Lime
  test : should contain all customers and item_names can be subset of train(15% of complete data)
       Customer  item
         A     carrot
         A     grape
         A     watermelon
         B     papaya
         B     Lime
```

Comment: For example, customer A and item Orange, there is only 2 entry. In such cases, it is not possible to get them divided into 3 buckets. If you can post sample expected data for 3 buckets as you need, then it will be helpful.

Comment: @parth , modified it , any inputs on above problem

Comment: Answer by @Serdar ERİÇ seems to the easiest way to achieve what you want. But it will fail if some ( customer, item ) combination has very few examples. If you know that in your actual data this is not the case, then it is fine to go, otherwise you need to write custom code wherein you have to do random sampling for each (customer, item) combination.

Answer (score 2):

As @Parth mentioned in the comments, first you need to have a dataset that is eligible for such stratified split. Then, you may create a new column with the combination of "Customer" and "item_name" to feed the "stratify" argument of "train_test_split" method, which is a part of sklearn.

Hereunder, you may find an example.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Create sample data
data = {
    "Customer":["A", "A", "A", "A","A","A","A","A","A", "B", "B", "B","B", "B", "B", "B","B","B"],
    "Orderid":[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "item_name":[
        "orange",
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "apple"
       ]
}
# Convert data to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Create a new column with combination of "Customer" and "item_name" to feed the "stratify" parameter
# train_test_split method which is a part of "sklearn.model_selection"
df["CustAndItem"] = df["Customer"]+"_"+df["item_name"]

# First split the "train" and "test" set. In this example I have split %40 of the data as "test"
# and %60 of data as "train"
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.index,
                                                    df["CustAndItem"],
                                                    test_size=0.4,
                                                    stratify=df["CustAndItem"])

# Get actual data after split operation
df_train = df.loc[X_train].copy(True)
df_test = df.loc[X_test].copy(True)

# Now split "test" set to "validation" and "test" sets. In this example I have split them equally 
# (test_size = 0.5) which will contain %20 of the main set.
X_validate, X_test, y_validate, y_test = train_test_split(df_test.index,
                                                          df_test["CustAndItem"],
                                                          test_size= 0.5,
                                                          stratify=df_test["CustAndItem"])
# Get actual data after split
df_validate = df_test.loc[X_validate]
df_test = df_test.loc[X_test]

# Print results
print(df_train)
print(df_validate)
print(df_test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , if i decrease test size from 0.4 to 0.3 .i'm getting the following error.alueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
may i know why ?

Comment: This is because of the size of the data. For example, think of a dataframe with 5 rows. 2 of them have the same label and another 2 has another label and the last one has a completely different label. If you want to split this data into 2 dataframes homogeneously according to the label, that would not be possible. Because you have a label that has only 1 row. Probably, you get this error while splitting the validation and test set. So, may print the ``df_test`` and observe the rows which have a uniuqe ``CustAndItem`` value. Then, you may append more rows to balance your data.